# Cannot update PATH to accommodate Homebrew commands

Tags: installation, terminal, path, homebrew, zsh

I am attempting to install Homebrew on MacOS but keep getting the error `Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.` I have updated my .zshrc to include `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` but have had no such and continue to not be able to access brew commands. I am running MacOS BigSur and am attempting to set up a ruby coding environment.

Comment: If brew is is `/opt/homebrew/bin`, why don't you add this directory to your PATH, and add instead `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running /opt/homebrew/bin/brew doctor as noted in the warning as opposed to brew doctor I was given the correct notation for updating my .zshrc file export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH as opposed to export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH as indicated in several answers to similar questions. After running source ~/.zshrc and brew doctor the system confirmed the path had been updated properly.